# YCSB Execution Error

Tags: cassandra, hbase, ycsb

When i am running YCSB, i am getting the following error. I followed all the steps specified in YCSB git hub link, but still i am getting this error

```
Exception in thread "Thread-3" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.getSingleton()Lorg/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder;
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.bind(LoggerFactory.java:128)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.performInitialization(LoggerFactory.java:108)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.java:279)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:252)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:265)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper.<clinit>(ZooKeeper.java:93)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper.<init>(RecoverableZooKeeper.java:92)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZKUtil.connect(ZKUtil.java:107)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZooKeeperWatcher.<init>(ZooKeeperWatcher.java:157)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZooKeeperWatcher.<init>(ZooKeeperWatcher.java:131)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.getZooKeeperWatcher(HConnectionManager.java:1341)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.ensureZookeeperTrackers(HConnectionManager.java:584)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.locateRegion(HConnectionManager.java:846)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.locateRegion(HConnectionManager.java:821)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.finishSetup(HTable.java:234)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.<init>(HTable.java:174)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.<init>(HTable.java:133)
    at com.yahoo.ycsb.db.HBaseClient.getHTable(HBaseClient.java:118)
    at com.yahoo.ycsb.db.HBaseClient.update(HBaseClient.java:302)
    at com.yahoo.ycsb.db.HBaseClient.insert(HBaseClient.java:357)
    at com.yahoo.ycsb.DBWrapper.insert(DBWrapper.java:148)
    at com.yahoo.ycsb.workloads.CoreWorkload.doInsert(CoreWorkload.java:461)
    at com.yahoo.ycsb.ClientThread.run(Client.java:269)
Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper.<init>(RecoverableZooKeeper.java:92)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZKUtil.connect(ZKUtil.java:107)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZooKeeperWatcher.<init>(ZooKeeperWatcher.java:157)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZooKeeperWatcher.<init>(ZooKeeperWatcher.java:131)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.getZooKeeperWatcher(HConnectionManager.java:1341)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.ensureZookeeperTrackers(HConnectionManager.java:584)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.locateRegion(HConnectionManager.java:846)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.locateRegion(HConnectionManager.java:821)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.finishSetup(HTable.java:234)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.<init>(HTable.java:174)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.<init>(HTable.java:133)
    at com.yahoo.ycsb.db.HBaseClient.getHTable(HBaseClient.java:118)
    at com.yahoo.ycsb.db.HBaseClient.update(HBaseClient.java:302)
    at com.yahoo.ycsb.db.HBaseClient.insert(HBaseClient.java:357)
    at com.yahoo.ycsb.DBWrapper.insert(DBWrapper.java:148)
    at com.yahoo.ycsb.workloads.CoreWorkload.doInsert(CoreWorkload.java:461)
    at com.yahoo.ycsb.ClientThread.run(Client.java:269)
```

My zookeeper is running fine...
Why is it happening? can any one help me on this

Answer (score 0):

It's a dependency issue. The exception is telling you that it's failing to find this method:

```
org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.getSingleton()Lorg/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder;
//specifically 
getSingleton()
```

The class that contains the method is imported statically so instead of throwing a `NoClassDefFoundError` at the top level (which you can see being thrown later in your stack trace) it will throw the `NoSuchMethodError` exception.

You need to add the `slf4j` jar to your classpath.